# Avoid null checks when creating criteria

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I have a method that I use to filter some results from Mongo.

```
public List<Person> findPersons(String firstName, String lastName, String nickname) {
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    if (!isNullOrEmpty(firstName)) {
        criteria.and(FIRST_NAME).is(firstName);
    }

    if (!isNullOrEmpty(lastName)) {
        criteria.and(LAST_NAME).is(lastName);
    }

    if (!isNullOrEmpty(nickname)) {
        criteria.and(NICKNAME).is(nickname);
    }

    Query query = new Query(criteria);
    List<Person> persons = mongoOperations.findAll(query, Person.class);

    return persons;
}
```

I do this because sometimes firstName, lastName and nickname can be null. I would like to avoid the isNullOrEmpty. I found about elemMatch, but I'm not sure if this would help me.